# Android - How to be notified when user paste something

Tags: android, clipboard

I work on an application where I want to copy text from a remote computer to my phone. But if I copy text from my remote computer, I don't want to transfer it right away since maybe I will not copy it on my phone but will copy it somewhere else on my remote computer. Is there a way to be notified when the user paste something to fill the clipboard with the right thing at that moment.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but with Windows, it is possible to delay the clipboard rendering. You can update the clipboard with the format but the data itself will be pushed only if an application request it (if user paste data somewhere). (look https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649030(v=vs.85).aspx)

Is it something possible with Android ? For now, the only solution that I have is to fill the phone clipboard as soon as I copy something on the remote desktop. But it needs bandwidth for nothing and I would like to avoid that. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to be notified when the user paste something to fill the clipboard with the right thing at that moment.

No.

> Is it something possible with Android ?

No.

> For now, the only solution that I have is to fill the phone clipboard as soon as I copy something on the remote desktop

Or, use some more specific action on the remote desktop to indicate that you are sending text to the phone, rather than to the remote desktop's own clipboard.